# Browser scroll strange behaviour for sticky nav menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I'm trying to create sticky nav menu that should be on page bottom when website loads and move up when scrolling. That nav menu should stick to page top when it reaches the top part while scrolling. Now it works and sticks. But problem occurs when you scroll slowly. It goes up more than it should and only after some pixels returns back to it's place. Note that this behaviour is not reproduced while scrolling fast! What can be the cause of that "overscrolling" and what are suggestions to make it stop moving when reach precisely the top part ?

html code

```
<div class="menu"></div>
```

css code

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 2000px;
}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}

.fixed_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

jquery code

```
var menu_height = $('menu').height();
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(window_scroll >= window_height - menu_height){
        $('.menu').addClass("fixed_menu");
    }else{
        $('.menu').removeClass("fixed_menu");
    }
});
```

jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/6JZf8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small typo in your code...

```
var menu_height = $('.menu').height();
```

You missed the . to get the class menu

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/6JZf8/1/